# Select JSON from multiple rows by keys Postgress

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to return only the JSON from multiple rows where keys are matched. What am I missing?

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value) FROM jsonb_each((SELECT data from hit_count_13306823936951630992)) WHERE key IN ('8517', '1099');
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Comment: jsonb_each can only used with one JSON record and your sub query is returning multiple JSON records. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes, how do I correct it to have the expected behavior? I have used `SELECT jsonb_object_agg(data_timestamp,data) FROM hit_count_13306823936951630992` for example to create a single JSON object. But Im not sure how to access the inner objects per timestamp key at that point...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call jsonb_each once for each row, not on the rows collectively.  You can do this with a lateral join.

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value) FROM hit_count_13306823936951630992 
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(data) WHERE key IN ('8517', '1099');
```

The LATERAL keyword is optional, since set-returning functions are always lateral.

Answer (score 0):

The following finds each instance of a given key per row creates a new object and aggregates the objects into a single object. While I consider this sub optimal. It fulfills the purpose.

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(data_timestamp, jsonb_build_object('8517',data->'8517','1099',data->'1099')) FROM hit_count_13306823936951630992;
```